# UICollectionView Shows blank screen/ Images does not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UICollectionView control in which i want to display images in grid. But when I run the code it shows black blank screen.

I have separate class for `cell - ColViewCell`, `cell identifier=Cell`
Also I have attached classes.

My code is as follows.

**ColViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
@interface ColViewController : UICollectionViewController     
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *imgArray;       
@end
```

**ColViewController.m**

```
#import "ColViewController.h"
#import "ColViewCell.h"

@interface ColViewController ()

@end

@implementation ColViewController
@synthesize  imgArray;

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    imgArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a1.png",@"a2.png",@"a3.png",@"a4.png",@"b1.png",@"b2.png",@"b3.png",nil];

    self.collectionView.dataSource=self;

    self.collectionView.delegate=self;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [imgArray count];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    ColViewCell  *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];    

    UIImage *image1;  

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imgArray[row]];

    cell.imageView.image=image1;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

**ColViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ColViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

**ColViewCell.m**

```
#import "ColViewCell.h" 

@implementation ColViewCell  

@synthesize imageView;

@end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here is the article about how to ask a question in here - 
 http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your ColViewController.m viewDidLoad method

```
[collectionView registerClass:[ColViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the issue, you should effort to give more explanation. Comment like answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Nothing happened by adding this line. It is showing an error. then i wrote [self.collectionView..........] instead of [collectionView.......], but still not showing images.

Comment: have you set the identifier of cell in storyboard?

Comment: just set the identifier of cell and remove the registerClass code and also change the background color of the cell. Hope it ll work.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't register in ViewDidload 
Paste This In View did load

```
[_collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ColViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];
```

Comment: I don't have nib file. I am using storyboard.

Comment: [_collectionView registerClass:[ColViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier];
Then Use This Method and please mark my answer right if u agreed :)

Comment: Set the identifier of collection view in storyboard same as u given in code